# Ошибка при изменении объекта сразу после создания

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-model

Мне нужно выполнять некоторые действия сразу после создания объекта модели, но мой код почему-то выдаёт ошибку. База данных используется PostgreSQL.

Минимальный код, в котором присутствует проблема:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Mailing(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.TextField()

def do_mailing(instance):
    instance.status = "Запущена"
    instance.save()
    #Некоторые длительные действия...
    instance.status = "Завершена"
    instance.save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=Mailing)
def start_mailing(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        t = threading.Thread(target=do_mailing, args=(instance,))
        t.start()
```

Ошибка:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_example_mailing_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(46) already exists.
```

Я пробовал сделать в начале функции do_mailing добавить time.sleep(5). Оно исправило проблему, но это костыль.